# Need Explanation for ListNode Solution

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

Been studying for the exam, but I can't understand why the solution is working below, it only assigned value to the curr.next node, but where is the value for curr.current? Can anyone be so kind to explain. Thanks!

The question:
You are given two non-empty linked lists representing two non-negative integers. The digits are stored in reverse order and each of their nodes contain a single digit. Add the two numbers and return it as a linked list.

You may assume the two numbers do not contain any leading zero, except the number 0 itself.

Example:

> Input: (2 -> 4 -> 3) + (5 -> 6 -> 4)
>
> Output: 7 -> 0 -> 8
> Explanation: 342 + 465 = 807.

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        ListNode dummyHead = new ListNode(0);
        ListNode p = l1, q = l2, curr = dummyHead;
        int carry = 0;
        while (p != null || q != null) {
            int x = (p != null) ? p.val : 0;
            int y = (q != null) ? q.val : 0;
            int sum = carry + x + y;
            carry = sum / 10;
            curr.next = new ListNode(sum % 10);
            curr = curr.next;
            if (p != null) p = p.next;
            if (q != null) q = q.next;
        }
        if (carry > 0) {
            curr.next = new ListNode(carry);
        }
        return dummyHead.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `curr.current`?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog it's my way of asking how to get the current value, specifically the first index. The API however is  in the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before starting the loop, there is a sentinel node `dummyHead` defined for the sake of implementation ease. We need to return `dummyHead->next` because from `dummyHead->next`, the actual linked list begins.

So, inside the loop, on each iteration, we actually start from the "previous" node and set `curr.next` and forwarded our linked list by `curr = curr.next` which is actually the "current".

Comment: Ahhh, I get it! Thanks. But would using curr.val instead of curr=curr.next be valid as well?

Comment: @BalDee Did you try it?

Comment: `curr.next` is actually an object of `ListNode` which might have `val` to store digit.

Comment: @OleV.V. yeah, for some reasons direct assignment of curr = new ListNode(sum % 10) gives me a blank output. What gives?

Comment: excellent tutorial.